# selecting records from particular column and row from a table with no keys in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table[image]

Record no 4 of column F3 is always valid date.. I need to pull it

i.e

```
select F3 from tbl where id=4
```

(but i dont have any pks to select it, but 4th record of F3 is always valid date)

How can i achieve it?

above table has no PK because i pulled it from excel worksheet as below

```
SELECT *,'kbl' as bank  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\rbl\kbl.xls;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
```

)

Comment: You just deleted that question and reasked it. Please don't do that in the future.

Comment: sir, is it a bad question?

Comment: Your tables should always have a primary key (or a unique constraint.)

Comment: i pulled it from excel , it is virtual table

Comment: There is no such thing as the "4th row" in a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ISDATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function to check whether it's a valid date.
Return 1 if a valid

[Demo example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59618/1)

```
CREATE table datetimedemo (f3 varchar(50));

INSERT into datetimedemo values('12-Nov-13');
INSERT into datetimedemo values('12-Nov');

-- Gives the valid date 12-Nov-13    

Select f3 from datetimedemo
where isdate(f3) = 1;
```

Comment: @timus2001 Not a single question in this world is bad, but the way you asked it might be bad. Remember to provide more information with your question so other SO users can help you with ease. read this http://tinyurl.com/so-hints by jon skeet.